# How do you return a value from an imported csv if a condition is met using python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a two column csv file. Column 1 is string values, column 2 is integer values. If a term is found in a string in Column 1 I want to return the corresponding value in Column 2.

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| green | 3 |
| red | 6 |

If Col1 contains "ed" return the corresponding row value in Col2, in this case 6.

Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
# Read the CSV file into a pandas DataFrame
file_name = input("Enter file name: ")
df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
string1 = input("Enter search term: ")
#check if each element in the DataFrame contains the partial string
matches = df.apply(lambda col: col.astype(str).str.contains(string1, case=False))
#get the row and column indices where the partial string matches
rows, cols = matches.values.nonzero()
for row, col in zip(rows, cols):
    print(f"Match found at Row: ", row)
```

Comment: What if the input string is `'e'`? Should it return `3` or `6`?

Answer (score 0):

Try reading into an array, then query the array:

```
 import pandas as pd

# Read the CSV file into a pandas DataFrame
file_name = input("Enter file name: ")
df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
searchstring = input("Enter search term: ")

# Search for searchstring in Col1 and return the corresponding value in Col2
result = df.loc[df['Col1'] == searchstring, 'Col2'].values

if len(result) > 0:
    print("The corresponding value of Col2 for your search in Col1 is:", result[0])
else:
    print("No corresponding value found for %s in Col1.", searchstring)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct nor efficient way to do this in pure pandas. You will have to loop over the values in "Col1".

Better convert your DataFrame to dictionary and use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) with a generator:

```
# for the demo, you can read from a file
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': ['green', 'red'], 'Col2': [3, 6]})

# convert to dictionary
dic = df.set_index('Col1')['Col2'].to_dict()

string1 = 'ed'

# find the first matching key, if any, else return None
out = next((v for k,v in dic.items() if string1 in k), None)
```

Output: `6`

If you can have multiple matches, using `zip` is a good approach.

Full code, reading from a file:

```
import pandas as pd

file_name = input("Enter file name: ")
df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
string1 = input("Enter search term: ")

for key, value in zip(df['Col1'], df['Col2']):
    if string1 in key:
        print(f'Match found at Row: {value}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `df.str.contains` to index with a boolean value, as follows:

```
df.loc[df['Col1'].str.contains('ed'), 'Col2']
```

Which gives you the index and value.

I can explain how it works if you need. Just comment below.